# Can I get PropertyInfo for a field or property in a class without using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, expression

I have tried searching around using Expressions but not able to find something by which I can access the fields or properties of a class without using reflection.

Basically, I will get a string at runtime, and I know that that string will be a property of the class, but I need to validate that it indeed is a property inside that class.

e.g. If I have a class:

```
class Test { string a; public string b {get;set;} }
```

I get the string values `a` and `b` at runtime and I need to verify that they exist inside the class `Test`

What I know till now from researching is that I can do:

```
string one = "a";
string two = "b";
PropertyInfo result1 = typeof(Test).GetProperty(one);
PropertyInfo result2 = typeof(Test).GetProperty(two);
```

But this code is using reflection. I want to know if there is some way I can do this without using reflection?

Can I do this using Expressions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is not possible without reflection. The only way I see is to cache the result values for reflection to avoid multiple reflection calls for the same type. Even an Expression has to use reflection to collect the information. If you try to collect a value from a property using `propertyInfo.GetValue(instance, null)` it can be boosted in performance using expression trees but you still need reflection to build this expression. Once build it can ce cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an expression, you can get the a `PropertyInfo` the following way:

```
    Test t = new Test();
    t.b = "sadf";
    Expression<Func<string>> exp = () => t.b;
    var memExp = exp.Body as MemberExpression;
    MemberInfo member = memExp.Member;
    PropertyInfo property = (PropertyInfo)member;
    Console.WriteLine(property.GetValue(t));
```

This will output the value of your property of your variable (`sadf` in the example). But what do you want to achieve? Why don't you collect the `PropertyInfo` from the `Type`? Because it is quite possible that under the hood, this code will use reflection the very same way you did (the same as LINQ still uses loop, but the programer just doesn't see it).

Comment: How do you create the expression `() => t.b` if you only have a string that contains the name of the property? I only see `Expression.Property(..., typeof().GetProperty(<str>))` that is still using reflection.

Comment: @SebastianSchumann, yes you are right. I wanted to get from the string. So that means, it is not possible without reflection.